# 'Font' is not convertible to 'Font?' Swift UI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

apparently I'm having this error that says 'Font is not convertible to 'Font?' in the code. Any suggestions ? Thanks! Here is the code below. I'm not sure exactly what's causing the issue. Everything seems to be fine before this.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDoItems()) var toDoItems:FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

    @State private var newTodoItem = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Section(header: Text("What's next ?")) {
                    HStack{
                        TextField("New Item", text: self.$newTodoItem)
                        Button(action: {
                            let toDoItem = ToDoItem(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                            toDoItem.Title = self.newTodoItem
                            toDoItem.createdAt = Date()

                            do {
                                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }

                            self.newTodoItem = ""

                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                    }
                }.font(.headline)
                Section(header: Text("To Do's")) {
                    ForEach(self.toDoItems) {todoItem in
                        ToDoItemView(title: todoItem.title!, createdAt: "\(todoItem.createdAt!)")

                    }
                }
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("My List"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it compilable you need explicitly specify type here

```
}.font(Font.headline)
```

and here

```
.foregroundColor(Color.green)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the `Button` action:

```swift
toDoItem.Title = self.newTodoItem
```

Change `Title` to `title`.

In general, when you get weird error messages in SwiftUI, just try to comment out lines until the error goes away. This will help you find the problematic code.